# Using select on the same attribute twice

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a database initialized like this:

```
Players{
Pid int primary key,
tid int not null references Teams,
name text not null,
age int not null
}

Teams{
tid int primary key,
name text not null,
location not null
}

Possessions{
id int primary key,
pid int not null references Players,
time timestamp not null, //the time the possession started for a player
held int not null //for how much time he had the ball
}
```

I would like to create a view called Teampasses where I can select `(passer,passee)` as follows:Passer and passe must be from the same team and passes possession starting time equals to passes possession starting time +held (time he has the ball). What I have done so far is this:

```
CREATE VIEW TeamPasses AS
SELECT PL.name AS P1,PL.name as P2
FROM Players as PL,Possessions as PO,Teams as T
Where P2.PO.time=P1.PO.time+P1.PO.held AND P2.T.tid=P1.T.tid
```

What I would like to ask is this: Is this `P2.PO.time` valid?
If not how could this be done correctly?

Comment: Use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years!

Answer (score 0):

You need two instances of `Possessions`. Join each `pid` to the other tables (in pairs) for more name details on passer and passee.

```
select *
from Possessions ps1 inner join Possessions ps2
    on ps2.gid = ps1.gid /* would it make more sense to share a common game id? */
        and ps2."time" = ps1."time" + ps1.held
```

Comment: Yes although I wonder if there's some concept of games or matches missing also.

Comment: You're right. I keep finding myself trying to understand the model while scrolling up and down on my phone. That's probably why I wrote it that way the first time. Without a better description of what `Possessions` actually represent it's a bit silly to speculate beyond the original idea I was trying to convey: OP needs to instances of `Possessions` in order to link them up consecutively.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
CREATE VIEW TeamPasses
AS

SELECT x.name AS PassedFrom
    ,y.name AS PassedTo
FROM (
    SELECT p.name
        ,p.tid
        ,s.[TIME]
        ,s.held
    FROM possessions s
    INNER JOIN players p ON s.pid = p.pid
    ) x
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT p.name
        ,p.tid
        ,s.[TIME]
    FROM possessions s
    INNER JOIN players p ON s.pid = p.pid
    ) y ON x.tid = y.tid
    AND x.[TIME] + x.held = y.[TIME]
```