# Multiple inner joins in a query

Tags: sql

```
Players{
Pid int primary key,
tid int not null references Teams,
name text not null,
age int not null
}

Teams{
tid int primary key,
name text not null,
location not null
}

Possessions{
id int primary key,
pid int not null references Players,
time int not null, //the time the possession started for a player
held int not null //for how much time he had the ball
}
```

I would like to create a view called Teampasses where I can select (passer,passee) as follows:Passer and passe must be from the same team and passes possession starting time equals to passes possession starting time +held (time he has the ball). What I have done so far is this:

```
SELECT x.name AS passer,y.name as Pasee
FROM player x
INNER JOIN player y ON x.tid=y.tid
INNER JOIN possesions p ON p.pid=x.pid AND p.pid=y.pid AND ...
```

in the `...` section right of `AND` i would like to do something like `x.time+x.held=y.time`.How could i refer to there two?

Comment: `x.time+x.held=y.time` should work just fine there. What is the error you get?

Comment: Looks like the same question as: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57681025/using-select-on-the-same-attribute-twice/57681218?noredirect=1#comment101810456_57681218

Comment: please use some conventional name, it difficult to understand your problems

Answer (score 0):

I see an issue with your data:

Your `Possessions` table only has a single foreign key to the `Players` table for the `passer`. It needs to also include the `Pid` of the `Passee`. Otherwise, there's no way to filter out which player on the `passer` `team` is the `Passee` for a given `Possession`.

I would suggest changing the `Possessions` table as follows:

```
    Possessions(
       id int primary key,
       pid_passer int not null references Players,
       pid_passee int not null references Players,
       time int not null, //the time the possession started for a player
       held int not null //for how much time he had the ball
       )
```

With this change, your data will work and the query becomes trivial.